# Save page source from Amazon in Java

Tags: java, eclipse

I am trying to save a page source from Amazon so I can see the price of an item. When I try to save it to a file, it only saves about 60 lines, most of them being white space. I can see the source from my browser and it is thousands of lines long. It goes for any page that I am trying to search. Heres the link I tried: [http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B015WCV70W/ref=s9_simh_gw_g147_i2_r?ie=UTF8&fpl=fresh&pf_rd_m=ATVPDKIKX0DER&pf_rd_s=desktop-2&pf_rd_r=0XHXJAF2NQ35BP5Y435K&pf_rd_t=36701&pf_rd_p=dc68ddd1-99ac-45e5-8c23-e9e0811a2b2c&pf_rd_i=desktop](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B015WCV70W)

Is there an easier way to do this?

Here's my code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class DownloadPage {

    public static final Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        System.out.print("Enter URL: ");
        savePage(in.nextLine());

    }

    static void savePage(String entURL) throws IOException{
        URL url = new URL(entURL);
        URLConnection con = url.openConnection();
        InputStream is = con.getInputStream();

        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("text.txt"));
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        String line = null;
        int count = 0;
        while (br.ready()) {
            bw.write(br.readLine());
            bw.newLine();
            count++;
        }
        line = null;
        bw.close();
        System.out.println("wrote successfully " + count);
    }
}
```

Sorry if I didn't format it right, its my first post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you use br.ready(), so every network pause cause the end of cycle
This block gives me 20632 lines of html

```
int count = 0;
while (true) {
    String line = br.readLine();
    if (line == null) {
        break;
    }
    bw.newLine();
       count++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The url is just a load point for a javascript app, which renders the HTML into your browser.

If you want to capture the *rendered* page, try [Selenium/WebDriver](http://www.seleniumhq.org/projects/webdriver/) which emulates a browser (and will run a javascript app).